# React v.18 & React-Bootstrap v.5.0 - Toggle switch with dynamic checked unchecked attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, uiswitch

**Library**: React v.18.0

**CSS**: React-bootstrap v.5.0 framework

**Component**: Toggle switch

**Official toggle switch documentation**: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/forms/checks-radios/#switches

**Requirement**: To have one switch with dynamic checked and unchecked attribute in the `<Form.Check` using `let` or `useState` hook.

Try 1: Used `if...else` expression in `return` statement to toggle the `checked` and `unchecked` attribute.

Try 2: Took the `<Form.Check` to a different function and did an if else with 2 separate `<Form.check` one with `checked` attribute another with `unchecked` attribute.

> Coder view: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ug9ffy?file=src%2FApp.js

> User view: https://react-ug9ffy.stackblitz.io

Comment: So, what's the question? For rendering data on the screen you should use usestate.

Comment: How to attach and remove the ```checked``` object in ```<Form.check``` dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Boolean value in the `checked` attribute:

```
export default function App() {
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false)

  function verifyCheck() {
    if(check) {
      setCheck(false)
    } else {
      setCheck(true)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Check // prettier-ignore
        checked={check}
        type="switch"
        id="custom-switch"
        label="Bill gates"
        onClick={verifyCheck}
      />
      <Form.Check // prettier-ignore
        checked
        disabled
        type="switch"
        label="Steve Jobs"
        id="disabled-custom-switch"
      />
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am calling an external API through axios. Imagine while an end-user visiting the page, there will be rows of toggle button based on the API response the toggle button's state should be displayed. Technically, ```useState(false)``` instead of ```false``` there should be a variable controlling the component's ```useState``` hook.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you want a variable amount of checkboxes. To do this and to control the states of it, you should make an external component for a checkbox.

Something like this:

```
export default function App() {

//get data from api somewhere and set it in a state

  return (
    <Form>
        {yourCheckboxesFromAPI.map((item) => (<CheckBox data={item} />))}
    </Form>
  );
}


export default function CheckBox(item){
const [check, setCheck] = useState(false)

return (
    <Form.Check
        checked={check}
        disabled
        type="switch"
        label={item.label} //steve-jobs
        id="disabled-custom-switch"
        onClick={() => setChecked(!checked)}
    />
);
}
```

Comment: I thought to delete this question but due to community standards I didn't. Here is the actual question which also contains stackblitz deployment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647562/edit-and-set-state-without-re-rendering-in-an-infinite-loop

Comment: I figured out the solution. ```prev``` of ```useState``` is the solution. while saving ```rowData``` we have to use ```prevRowData``` which is ```setRowData(prevRowData => [...prevRowData]);```