# Edit and set state without re-rendering in an infinite loop

Tags: react-hooks, state, rendering, infinite-loop, array.prototype.map

I couldn't edit the value in a component and save the value using `useState` as it is throwing the below error:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

My objective is to,

- Display the component with values that are received from the `rowData`.
- Edit the value that are received from the `rowData` and save it back to `rowData`.

The rendering starts from the function `editPropertyValue(settings, index)` where it evaluates data type to render the value in respective component such as `input` or `checkbox`. If datatype is `text` then component is `<input`; if datatype is `boolean` or `'true'` or `'false'` `string` then component is `checkbox`.

Finally, it calls the `getSuitableEditField(settings, fieldType, id);` where I am trying to display the value that is received from the `rowData`. Assume that `rowData` is from API using axios `GET` call.

**Try**: I tried to implement `useEffect()` for unmounting and mounting the component with new data but still got odd errors.

The below code in stackblitz, `getSuitableEditField` has the implementation with issue.

If you double click on the middle column value, you can see the issue. Click on any value under `Property Value`.
Please help or hint a clue,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rzeclq?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Fstyle.css

Comment: Okay 1 thing that comes to my mind in case of an infinite loop: You could add a dependency to your useEffect. Now the use effect will execute on every render.

Comment: How do we add ```useEffect ``` in line number  ```102 ``` :  ```setPropertyValue( settings.value ); ``` and  ```120 ```:  ```setUserValue(value); ```

Comment: Another thing that maybe causes issues is that you are editing the rowData array state directly and then setting the state with it. I think you need to make a new array and set the state with that new array (incuding the original rowData data). Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100863/how-to-set-state-array-using-react-hooks

Comment: I mean dependency in UseEffect hook on line 66. Example: navigate or userValue or apikey/token or whatever. Your data will only be called once at the start and when a dependency changes in that case.

Comment: I have added dependencies on line number ```66``` Try 1:   }, ```[ rowData, propertyValue, userValue ]);```. Try 2: ```[ rowData ]);``` but still it is re-rending.

Comment: yeah look you are setting rowData in the useEffect. So now you are saying: when rowData changes, please execute the code in this useEffect. This causes a loop. That it the function of a dependency array (the [] after a useEffect)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100863/how-to-set-state-array-using-react-hooks?noredirect=1&lq=1 discusses about the setting of data in an array. My scenario is to ```setUserValue``` && ```setPropertyValue``` using ```useState``` hook and then modify the value which was set using ```useState``` hook. Did you mean to do a copy of array and then use it for modifications and assign it back to ```rowData```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256252/discussion-between-common-man-and-takkie253).

Comment: The official documentation has given these https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#im-getting-an-error-too-many-re-renders but there I have followed the correct convention, eg: ```return <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}>Click me</button>```

Comment: I figured out the solution. ```prev``` of ```useState``` is the solution. while saving ```rowData``` we have to use ```prevRowData``` which is ```setRowData(prevRowData => [...prevRowData]);```